# Passing a C++ function to a Python functional within C++ with Pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I want to call the Python functional `eval` from a C++11 code, using a function defined there as the argument of `eval`.

`my_module.py`

```
def eval(foo):
   return foo(1)
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

double foo (double x) { return x; };
auto foo_py = py::vectorize(foo);

int main()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::module m = py::module::import("my_module");

    m.attr("eval")(foo_py);
}
```

The code compiles but I get the following error, which I do not understand:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::cast_error'
> what():  Unable to convert call argument '0' of type 'detail::vectorize_helper (*)(double), double, double>' to Python object

Comment: Every example of `py::vectorize` I can find feeds it to `module.def("name", py::vectorize(....));`.

Comment: Right, I got this to work with ```PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(emb, m) { m.def("foo", py::vectorize(foo)); }; py::module em = py::module::import("emb"); m.attr("eval")(emb.attr("foo"));```
I wonder if there is a more "direct" way, though; for example, ```m.attr("eval")(foo);``` also fails due to casting issues.